# Square of the sample mean from a Normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, statistical-inference

Let $X$ be the mean of a random sample of size $n$ from a $N(θ,σ^2)$ distribution, $−∞ < θ < ∞$ and $σ^2 > 0$. Assume that $σ^2$ is known.

Show that $X^2 - (σ^2)/n$  is an unbiased estimator of $θ$, and find its efficiency.

Some hints about the distribution of $X^2$?

Thanks.

Comment: To find whether given estimator is unbiased you need to find its expected value, not the distribution.

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow you. How can I find the Expectation of X^2 without knowing its distribution??

Comment: Use the properties of expectations. And check the edit made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only true when $\theta = 0$ or $\theta =1$. Assuming $X_1,\ldots, X_n\stackrel{\mathrm{i.i.d.}}\sim N(\theta,\sigma^2)$, the Bienaymé formula yields
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(\bar X_n) &= \operatorname{Var}\left(\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)\\
&= \frac1{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Var}(X_i)\\
&= \frac1{n^2} n\sigma^2\\
&= \frac{\sigma^2}n.
\end{align}
Since the second moment of the sample mean is given by
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[\bar X_n^2] &= \operatorname{Var}(\bar X_n) + \mathbb E[\bar X_n]^2\\
&= \frac{\sigma^2}n + \mathbb E\left[\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right]^2\\
&= \frac{\sigma^2}n +\frac1{n^2}\cdot(n\theta)^2\\
&= \frac{\sigma^2}n + \theta^2,
\end{align}
it is clear that
$$
\mathbb E\left[\bar X_n^2 -\frac{\sigma^2}n \right] = \frac{\sigma^2}n + \theta^2 - \frac{\sigma^2}n = \theta^2,
$$
and $\theta^2 = \theta$ implies that $\theta\in\{0,1\}$.